# Bootstrap-3 panel footer doesn't fill panel

Tags: css, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm working on a responsive web admin single page application, I'm using `Bootstrap 3` and `AngularJS 1.4.8`, I created a panel and I put a form inside that panel, I put the footer inside the form with two buttons.

My problem is that the panel footer doesn't cover/fill the panel length.

Do I need to put the footer inside the `form` so the button could send the information or if I put the footer outside the `form` the button can send the info anyway?

I think that the problem is that I created a `<div class="col-lg-12">` 
to put the panel heading and inside this `div` I created another `<div class="col-lg-6">` to put the panel content so that's why the panel footer doesn't cover the entire panel.

I tried putting the footer outside of the `<div class="col-lg-6">` and it worked but if do this the button will be outside of the `form`. Does this matter it seems to me like a bad practice putting the button outside of the `form`.

Here is my html code

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h1 class="page-header">Create User</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                Basic Form Elements
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <form role="form">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Name:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="user name">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <label>Email:</label>
                                <input class="form-control" placeholder="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                                <div class="pull-right">
                                    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                    <!-- /.col-lg-6 (nested) -->
                </div>
                <!-- /.row (nested) -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.panel-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.panel -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
</div>
<!-- /.row -->
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the `panel-footer` div outside the `panel-body` div.

This div should start *after* the `panel-body` div has been closed. You'll need to restructure your form so the submit button is still inside or you'll have to use javascript / jQuery to submit it if you don't want to do this.

You can see example usages of different panel components in the bootstrap [components](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#panels) section for panels.

Fixed [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/E4G7jeH3BF)

Answer (score 1):

The reason your panel-footer is not properly aligned at the bottom of the panel is because you have it inside of the panel-body. Your panel-heading, panel-body, and panel-footer should all be separate components inside the panel itself.

Simply try removing the panel-footer from inside panel-body.

This will mean that the buttons will be outside of the form, but you can't carry form content over multiple divs. If you'd like to avoid removing the buttons from the form, you may have to leave them in the body and perhaps style them similarly to how a panel-footer would look.